# invalid value encountered in true_divide in rk45

Tags: astronomy, runge-kutta

I'm trying to implement to RK45 for a two body problem with the earth and sun but keep getting a division by zero that I don't understand. It seems to be in the norme from the accelerations function that the division occurs but I don't see how that can be or how to fix it. Here is code:

```
from scipy import optimize
from numpy import linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

AU=1.5e11
a=AU
e=0.5
mss=2E30
ms = 2E30
me = 5.98E24
mv=4.867E24
yr=3.15e7
h=100
mu1=ms*me/(ms+me)
mu2=ms*me/(ms+me)
G=6.67E11
step=24

vi=np.sqrt(G*ms*(2/(a*(1-e))-1/a))
#sun=sphere(pos=vec(0,0,0),radius=0.1*AU,color=color.yellow)
#earth=sphere(pos=vec(1*AU,0,0),radius=0.1*AU)

sunpos=np.array([-903482.12391302, -6896293.6960525, 0.  ])
earthpos=np.array([a*(1-e),0,0])

earthv=np.array([0,vi,0])
sunv=np.array([0,0,0])





def accelerations(t,earthposs, sunposs):
    norme=sum( (earthposs-sunposs)**2 )**0.5
    gravit = G*(earthposs-sunposs)/norme**3
    sunaa = me*gravit
    earthaa = -ms*gravit
    return earthaa, sunaa

def ode45(f,t,y,h):
        """Calculate next step of an initial value problem (IVP) of an ODE with a RHS described
        by the RHS function with an order 4 approx. and an order 5 approx.
        Parameters:
        t: float. Current time.
        y: float. Current step (position).
        h: float. Step-length.
        Returns:
        q: float. Order 2 approx.
        w: float. Order 3 approx.
        """

        s1 = f(t, y[0],y[1])
        s2 = f(t + h/4.0, y[0] + h*s1[0]/4.0,y[1] + h*s1[1]/4.0)
        s3 = f(t + 3.0*h/8.0, y[0] + 3.0*h*s1[0]/32.0 + 9.0*h*s2[0]/32.0,y[1] + 3.0*h*s1[1]/32.0 + 9.0*h*s2[1]/32.0)
        s4 = f(t + 12.0*h/13.0, y[0] + 1932.0*h*s1[0]/2197.0 - 7200.0*h*s2[0]/2197.0 + 7296.0*h*s3[0]/2197.0,y[1] + 1932.0*h*s1[1]/2197.0 - 7200.0*h*s2[1]/2197.0 + 7296.0*h*s3[1]/2197.0)
        s5 = f(t + h, y[0] + 439.0*h*s1[0]/216.0 - 8.0*h*s2[0] + 3680.0*h*s3[0]/513.0 - 845.0*h*s4[0]/4104.0,y[1] + 439.0*h*s1[1]/216.0 - 8.0*h*s2[1] + 3680.0*h*s3[1]/513.0 - 845.0*h*s4[1]/4104.0)
        s6 = f(t + h/2.0, y[0] - 8.0*h*s1[0]/27.0 + 2*h*s2[0] - 3544.0*h*s3[0]/2565 + 1859.0*h*s4[0]/4104.0 - 11.0*h*s5[0]/40.0,y[1] - 8.0*h*s1[1]/27.0 + 2*h*s2[1] - 3544.0*h*s3[1]/2565 + 1859.0*h*s4[1]/4104.0 - 11.0*h*s5[1]/40.0)
        w1 = y[0] + h*(25.0*s1[0]/216.0 + 1408.0*s3[0]/2565.0 + 2197.0*s4[0]/4104.0 - s5[0]/5.0)
        w2 = y[1] + h*(25.0*s1[1]/216.0 + 1408.0*s3[1]/2565.0 + 2197.0*s4[1]/4104.0 - s5[1]/5.0)
        q1 = y[0] + h*(16.0*s1[0]/135.0 + 6656.0*s3[0]/12825.0 + 28561.0*s4[0]/56430.0 - 9.0*s5[0]/50.0 + 2.0*s6[0]/55.0)
        q2 = y[1] + h*(16.0*s1[1]/135.0 + 6656.0*s3[1]/12825.0 + 28561.0*s4[1]/56430.0 - 9.0*s5[1]/50.0 + 2.0*s6[1]/55.0)

        return w1,w2, q1,q2
t=0
T=10**5
xarray=[]
yarray=[]
while t<T:
    ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)
    earthpos=ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)[1]
    sunpos=ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)[3]
    xarray.append(ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)[0][0])
    yarray.append(ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)[0][1])
    print(ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)[0][0],ode45(accelerations,t,[earthpos,sunpos],h)[0][1])
    t=t+h

plt.plot(xarray,yarray)
plt.savefig('orbit.png')
plt.show()
```

After the second iteration the code comes back with only nan values for the earthpos.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical integration methods usually integrate first order systems, `y'=f(t,y)`. You want to integrate a second order ODE system `y''=f(t,y)` which you first need to turn into a first order system.

Why do you not use the vector class of `numpy`?

Why do you perform the same computation with the same arguments multiple times instead of catching all return values once and then distributing them to the lists?

You could also use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` with the `"RK45"` method instead of programming it yourself.